# Want to know how to open a model in Solibri using the api method openModel

Tags: java, api

I want to write a code to open a model in Solibri using the method

```
public static Model openModel​(String name,  InputStream inputStream) throws ModelOpeningException
```

in Solibri api, but am unable to do it could someone explain how to go through this the file to be opened has an .smc extension. this is in java

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to following codes.

```
public void openModel(String name, InputSteam inputStream) throws ModelOpeningException{

 // Get solibri service for accessing models

 var models = SMC.getModels();

// Open model

 var model = models.openModel(name, inputStream);
 
 inputStream.close();

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).